# PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect not firing on some asbtract method

Tags: .net, postsharp

I can override some method like GetHashCode or my own abstract class but aspect not firing on SqlConnection.Open and Close

```
SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection("Password=qwsa;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa2;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=.");
a.Open(); // not firing
var zzzz = a.GetHashCode(); //firing
a.Close(); //not firing
Class1 class1 = new Class1(); //firing
var zzzzzzz=class1.testttt(); //not firing
```

**Here is my code**

```
[Serializable]
public class TestOverrideAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        //DoWORK
    }
}

#if DEBUG
[assembly: PostsharpAspects.TestOverrideAspect (AttributeTargetAssemblies = "*", AttributeTargetTypes = "*", AttributeInheritance=MulticastInheritance.Multicast )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, applying aspects on external assemblies is a sign of bad use, even though it is possible and in some cases necessary. This is especially true in case of `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` and abstract method where you want the aspect to actually change all overloads (if you specify the inheritance).

You should use `MethodInterceptionAspect` which has different theoretical background and works better in case you need. If you apply such aspect on `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open` it should work properly and should intercept the abstract method. You just don't have usual advices so you need to implement similar code yourself.

Please also note that we had a related bug in attribute multicasting, which was recently fixed, so please check that you have the latest version.